# Correct way to apply toFixed(2) on multiplied value of jQuery UI slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to apply toFixed on the multiplied value of a jQuery UI slider as so:

```
jQuery( "#width-amount-english" ).val(  jQuery( ".width-slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) * 0.393701.toFixed(2) + "in - " + jQuery( ".width-slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) * 0.393701.toFixed(2) +" in" );
```

The problem is that the `toFixed` is only applied to the multiplier instead of the entire multiplied value.
I have tried to add more brackets like `slider(( "values", 1 ) * 0.393701).toFixed(2)` and in other places but then I am starting to get errors such as "toFixed is not a function" etc.

What is the correct way/syntax to apply `toFixed(2)` to the entire calculated slider value?

**EDIT:** This is an example of the full code block:

```
     jQuery( ".width-slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
            step: 0.01,
            min: 0,
            max: 40.00,
            values: [ 8.38, 
                        24.91 
                            ],

            slide: function( event, ui ) {  
                jQuery( "#width-amount-metric" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " cm - " + ui.values[ 1 ] +"cm");
                jQuery( "#width-amount-english" ).val( (ui.values[ 0 ] * 0.393701).toFixed(2) + " in - " + (ui.values[ 1 ] * 0.393701).toFixed(2) +"in");
            },
            stop: function( event, ui ) {
                jQuery(".width-slider-range").trigger( "dblclick" );
            }
 });
jQuery( "#width-amount-metric" ).val(  jQuery( ".width-slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + "cm - " + jQuery( ".width-slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 )+"cm" );
jQuery( "#width-amount-english" ).val(  jQuery( ".width-slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) * 0.393701.toFixed(2) + "in - " + jQuery( ".width-slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) * 0.393701.toFixed(2) +" in" );
```

Comment: Basic Math ? Use `(` `)`

Comment: As I explained, I tried it, it errors

Comment: How do we try it out ? What does `jQuery( ".width-slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 )` return ?

Comment: @RayonDabre question edited

Comment: knowing `toFixed` is a **String** method may help

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To get the values from `slider` => Ref: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-values

```
var values = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "values" );
```

Assuming you have multiple values, Try this:

```
jQuery("#width-amount-english").val((jQuery(".width-slider-range").slider("option","values")[0] * 0.393701).toFixed(2) + "in - " + (jQuery(".width-slider-range").slider("option","values")[1] * 0.393701).toFixed(2) + " in");
```